# Can't get data fetched from my rails back-end api by middleware (createAsyncThunk) to the redux-store

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-redux, jwt

I'm trying to fetch data from my rails back-end API to the redux store. I can see the data when I console.log(data) inside the middleware(createAsyncThunk). However, I can't get it into the redux store.

src/redux/doctorsSlice

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import API from '../api/api';

const initialState = [];

export const getDoctors = createAsyncThunk(
  'doctors/getDoctors',
  async (token) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API}/doctors`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    console.log('responses', response);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data.doctors;
  },
);

export const doctorsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'doctors',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getDoctors.fulfilled]: (state, action) => action.payload,
  },

});

export default doctorsSlice.reducer;
```

src/redux/store

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import doctorsReducer from './doctorsSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    doctors: doctorsReducer,
  },
});
```

src/components/DoctorsList

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getDoctors } from '../redux/doctorsSlice';

const DoctorsList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getDoctors());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const { doctors } = useSelector((state) => state.doctors);

  return (
    <div className="">
      <h2>Doctors</h2>
    </div>

  );
};

export default DoctorsList;
```

src/componets/app

```
import DoctorsList from './DoctorsList';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="content">

        <DoctorsList />
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

src/index

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import store from './redux/store';
import { getDoctors } from './redux/doctorsSlice';

store.dispatch(getDoctors);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,

  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

I have followed the redux documentation. And I expect to see data in-store. But I get an empty array.
Pls, any help, support and constructive criticism on how I can solve this are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `getDoctors` function. I was suppose to `return data` in the last line of the function. Instead, I was initially returning `data.doctors` which does not hold the data.